# payment and receipt records display in single table using codeigniter and mysql

Tags: codeigniter

Model:

```
$this->db->where('payment_details.created_on >= ',$start_date);
    $this->db->where('payment_details.created_on <= ',$end_date);
    $this->db->where('receipt_details.created_on >= ',$start_date);
    $this->db->where('receipt_details.created_on <= ',$end_date);        
    $this->db->select('payment_details.id,payment_details.payment_no,payment_details.site_id,payment_details.vendor_id,payment_details.work,payment_details.description,payment_details.date,payment_details.amount,payment_details.tax_type,payment_details.tax,payment_details.subtotal,payment_details.grand_total,payment_details.created_on,receipt_details.id,receipt_details.receipt_no,receipt_details.site_id,receipt_details.vendor_id,receipt_details.work,receipt_details.description,receipt_details.date,receipt_details.amount,receipt_details.tax_type,receipt_details.tax,receipt_details.subtotal,receipt_details.grand_total,receipt_details.created_on,vendor.id,vendor.vname,site.id,site.sname');

$this->db->from('payment_details');        
$this->db->join('vendor','vendor.id=payment_details.vendor_id OR vendor.id=receipt_details.vendor_id','LEFT');
$this->db->join('site','site.id=payment_details.site_id OR site.id=receipt_details.site_id','LEFT');
return $this->db->get()->result();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYfe4.png)

I will try but there is error occur while running this query
Error:
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN `vendor` ON `vendor`.`id`=`payment_details`.`vendor_id` OR `vendor`.`i' at line 2

SELECT `payment_details`.`id`, `payment_details`.`payment_no`, `payment_details`.`site_id`, `payment_details`.`vendor_id`, `payment_details`.`work`, `payment_details`.`description`, `payment_details`.`date`, `payment_details`.`amount`, `payment_details`.`tax_type`, `payment_details`.`tax`, `payment_details`.`subtotal`, `payment_details`.`grand_total`, `payment_details`.`created_on`, `receipt_details`.`id`, `receipt_details`.`receipt_no`, `receipt_details`.`site_id`, `receipt_details`.`vendor_id`, `receipt_details`.`work`, `receipt_details`.`description`, `receipt_details`.`date`, `receipt_details`.`amount`, `receipt_details`.`tax_type`, `receipt_details`.`tax`, `receipt_details`.`subtotal`, `receipt_details`.`grand_total`, `receipt_details`.`created_on`, `vendor`.`id`, `vendor`.`vname`, `site`.`id`, `site`.`sname` LEFT JOIN `vendor` ON `vendor`.`id`=`payment_details`.`vendor_id` OR `vendor`.`id`=`receipt_details`.`vendor_id` LEFT JOIN `site` ON `site`.`id`=`payment_details`.`site_id` OR `site`.`id`=`receipt_details`.`site_id` WHERE `payment_details`.`created_on` >= '2018-05-01' AND `payment_details`.`created_on` <= '2018-05-31' AND `receipt_details`.`created_on` >= '2018-05-01' AND `receipt_details`.`created_on` <= '2018-05-31'

Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/construct/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
Thanks in advance......

Comment: missing from in the query

Comment: $this->db->from('payment_details'); and also your join structure should not be like this

Comment: yes that is the point you have to also include the receipt tables in join other wise you will not get the proper data, here you want to get data without including table how is that possible, you have four table and join only two

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: pls help me, how to change in codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you** : *(not tested)*

*your query structure should be like this, do necessary changes providing you just hint*

```
$sql = 'SELECT payment_details.id,payment_details.payment_no,payment_details.site_id,payment_details.vendor_id,payment_details.work,payment_details.description,payment_details.date,payment_details.amount,payment_details.tax_type,payment_details.tax,payment_details.subtotal,payment_details.grand_total,payment_details.created_on,receipt_details.id,receipt_details.receipt_no,receipt_details.site_id,receipt_details.vendor_id,receipt_details.work,receipt_details.description,receipt_details.date,receipt_details.amount,receipt_details.tax_type,receipt_details.tax,receipt_details.subtotal,receipt_details.grand_total,receipt_details.created_on,vendor.id,vendor.vname,site.id,site.sname 
        FROM payment_details  
        JOIN (vendor, receipt_details, site)
        ON (vendor.id=payment_details.vendor_id OR vendor.id=receipt_details.vendor_id
        AND site.id=payment_details.site_id OR site.id=receipt_details.site_id)';
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
return $query->result();
```

Comment: sorry double comma remove one

Comment: sir pls don't mind without seeing your code it little bit difficult for me to tell you from here,